# How to mark a caller as SPAM and autoignore incoming calls?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, phone

I bought BQ Aquaris E4.5.

I have a problem because I cannot find possibility to start ignoring incoming calls and messages from number that I don't want to speak with.

How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible at the moment, but the feature has been requested:

- [for calls](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/dialer-app/+bug/1469220)
- [for messages](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/messaging-app/+bug/1469535)

You can vote for the bugs, if you want.